# Jenkins: Maven Module view with Pipeline-Job

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to set up a Jenkins Pipeline-Job using Declarative Pipeleine.

So far so good, but one thing I'm missing in Jenkins after the build is the Maven Modlue View:
[image]

Maven is executed like

```
withMaven(jdk: '...', maven: '...', 
        options: [artifactsPublisher(),
                  dependenciesFingerprintPublisher()]) {
                sh 'mvn clean install'
            }
```

Am I missing something here or is that view simply not supported when working with a Pipeline-Job?

Maven-Version is > 3.3

Any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: The module view in Jenkins is based on the ability of Jenkins to scan the project structure befure the run of the build...this is not part of your pipeline and I don't think it's supported in Jenkins pipelines...apart from that what is the use case for the modules list?

Comment: Hmm ok, so it's not possible to scan the project structure before the build with pipeline jobs? Usecase is better readability because i.e. failed test results are grouped by module, another thing is that it's possible to view console-output for only one module etc. etc.